# Docker service depends, doesn't work after restart docker service

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Services in docker-compose with depends on condition (healthy) are working well after `docker-compose up -d`
But after restarting docker daemon (`service docker restart`) or server reboot, all services start at the same time and it seems that the depends on condition doesn't apply.

```
version: "2.4"
services:
      serviceA:
        ...
        restart: unless-stopped
        depends_on:
          serviceB:
            condition: service_healthy
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your text it seems like that you have syntax error and `condition :` part is wrong ! (didn't see anything on docker references about condition)

You should use `depends_on`

> Express dependency between services.

```
depends_on:
  - db
  - redis
redis:
   image: redis
db:
   image: postgres
```

The [following](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#depends_on) documentation will help you better

Comment: Syntax should be right, according to [this part of the docs of docker-compose version 2](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#depends_on)

Comment: Try to be specific about services like the article you mentioned above and see whats happen, and be sure that you are using a good `version` of `docker-compose`  for specific commands such as you mentioned

Comment: Please read my question again, everything is fine  when I try docker-compose up -d, I've setup healthchecks for my services, and I'm depending services based on them. but when I reboot the server, or restart the docker service, all of my services start at the same time.

Comment: Dear Ali , I read your question several times , when you restart all the services of your docker it's natural for containers to restart because you restarting all services including docker daemon that it should always run because docker engine needs it , so it's natural for all your services to restart and start again , but the condition command execute when service is not healthy according to your docker-compose.yml and an internal error accrue to your internal container services . For more questions and talking better you can contact me via hossein.nouri79@icloud.com